# php regex for parsing stock symbols in html code

Tags: php, html, regex

i have following php regex code.. i want to extract the stock symbol in some html output.

The stock symbol i want to extract is /q?s=XXXX -- XXXX (the stock symbol) could be 1 to 5 characters long.

```
  if(preg_match_all('~(?<=q\?s=)[-A-Z.]{1,5}~', $html, $out))
        {
            $out[0] = array_unique($out[0]);                
        } else {
            echo "FAIL";
        }
```

HTML code below (case 1 and case that i applied this to)

```
case #1 (does *not* work)
<a href="/q?s=BLCM" symbol="BLCM">Bellicum Pharmaceuticals, Inc.</a>

case #2 (does work correctly)                          
 <a href="/q?s=NYLD">NYLD</a>
```

Looking for suggestions on how i can update my php regex code to make it work for *both* case 1 and case 2. Thanks.

Comment: working https://regex101.com/r/fW2gH4/1

Comment: And the lookbehind is somewhat pointless. Just use a plain capture group or a `\K` kill switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regex, make effective use of [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and **XPath** to do this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[substring(@href, 1, 5) = "/q?s="]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
   $results[] = str_replace('/q?s=', '', $link->getAttribute('href'));
}

print_r($results);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/365932)

Comment: Or if the href value is always fixed, use `$results[] = substr($link->getAttribute('href'), 5);`

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems nice, but it seems like a lot of work and code to maintain, no?

```
if (preg_match_all('/q\?s=(\S{1,5})\"/', $html, $match)) {
    $symbols = array_unique($match[1]);
}
```

or even shorter... `'/q\?s=(\S+)\"/'`